# Unable to delete from core data, swift4

Tags: core-data, swift4

I am unable to delete data from core data. Below is my code. When I delete, the data gets deleted from table but once I navigate back it shows up again as it does not get deleted from core data. Thanks

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let data = (fav[indexPath.row])
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                  DataSave.deleteData(dataToDelete: data)
                fav.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)


            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

**My deleteData function** - 


    class func deleteData(dataToDelete:String) {
            let context = getContext()

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<City>(entityName: "City")
            if let fetchResults = try!context.fetch(fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as? [City] {
                for result in fetchResults{
                    if result.city_name == [dataToDelete] {
                        context.delete(result)
                        print("deleted from cored data")
                        do {
                            try context.save() 
                        } catch {
                            print("could not delete from core data")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Reload table view after context.save() (means after print("deleted from cored data") line)

Comment: But, my code doesn't print the statement "deleted from code data" or in do or catch block. It never reaches for loop, so it will not reload tableview in that block.

Comment: why do you put dataToDelete in an array when you compare it with city_name? `if result.city_name == [dataToDelete]` should probably be `if result.city_name == dataToDelete`